# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BlobBuilder' of undefined

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO to transfer info back and forth between RethinkDB and React.  I keep getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BlobBuilder' of undefined
```

whenever I try to run the file and, after some sleuthing, I was able to figure out that it came from my socket listener files.  Here's one for an example:

```
// ./socket-listeners/inventory-listener.js
// imported into index.jsx

import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io.connect('/');

const InventorySocketListener = (store) => {
    socket.on('item:insert', (item) => {
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'item:insert',
            item
        });
    });

    socket.on('item:update', (item) => {
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'item:update',
            item
        });
    });

    socket.on('item:delete', (item) => {
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'item:delete',
            item
        });
    });
};

export default InventorySocketListener;
```

As you can see, I have no BlobBuilder in there, and my own searching around taught me that it is deprecated (MDN).  I did make sure to update all of my npm packages also.  However, for the life of me, I can't figure out where exactly this is coming from or how to fix it.  Thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: _"I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BlobBuilder' of undefined`"_ , _"I can't figure out where exactly this is coming from or how to fix it."_ Does the error message list the line number of the error?

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah, line 37785 of my compiled scripts.js after webpack works its magic.  The list of functions is a series of anonymous functions from imported packages.

Comment: Did you try to run in Dev before compiling with webpack?

Comment: Where is 'store' of 'store.dispatch([callback])'?

Comment: Maybe you should you try to set `mangle: false` for the uglify in your webpack config file?

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer I'm only using webpack.  I have a feeling that the course I'm taking isn't fully developed. :(  Also, I'm not using any sort of mangle in this project

Comment: @NonCreature0714 This file gets imported into my index.jsx file and store gets passed into it there in a function call.

Comment: @JimStrother what are the loaders you use with webpack? You don't use uglify?

Comment: @dandavis I'm not sure I understand

Comment: @ShimonBrandsdorfer The only plugin I'm using is `transform-class-properties`

Comment: this is about a problem in node.js right? (or is the tag wrong?)

Comment: Sorry, @dandavis, I did select an extra tag.  My bad.

Comment: do you have something that tries to download or upload a file?

Comment: I'm building an item tracker that uses sockets for the data transfer, so I guess it's yes

Comment: one sure thing i would try if nothing else is dropping reqs one at a time, or in chunks until the issue goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with this and it turns out that the issue ended up being how 'socket.io-client' was being imported.  The fix ended up being `import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io';`.